# children could not be evaluated update method not being called blazor

Tags: api, blazor

I am trying to call the api to update the record from webproject using the following statement

```
public async Task UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            var employeeJson =
                new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(employee), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            await _httpClient.PutAsync("api/employee", employeeJson);             
        }
```

But when I debug the  variable employeeJson , to shows the error 'children could not be evaluated'
The data is passed to the variable employee as given below

```html
{
    "employeeId": 3,
    "firstName": "sfdsfdsfsd",
    "lastName": "fdgf",
    "birthDate": "2020-09-30T19:09:26.075",
    "email": "ppp@gmail.com",
    "street": "sdfdsfdsf",
    "zip": "sdfsdfds",
    "city": "sdfsdf",
    "countryId": 1,
    "country": {
        "countryId": 1,
        "name": "Belgium"
    },
    "phoneNumber": "1211",
    "maritalStatus": 0,
    "gender": 0,
    "comment": "sdfdsfds",
    "joinedDate": "2020-09-30T19:09:26.124",
    "exitDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
    "jobCategoryId": 1,
    "jobCategory": {
        "jobCategoryId": 1,
        "jobCategoryName": "Pie research"
    }
    
}
```

My web api startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "BethanysPieShopHRM"));

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IJobCategoryRepository, JobCategoryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
            });
             



            services.AddControllers();
            //.AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ca);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
      
        app.UseCors("Open");
       


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Repo to get the employee record

```
public Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeId)
        {
             
            return _appDbContext.Employees
                .Include(e => e.Country)
                .Include(e=>e.JobCategory)
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmployeeId == employeeId);
            
        }
```

I tried to update through postman, but the error message is being showed as
'Error 405 'Request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource

The method I am calling from the API controller  is as given below

```
[HttpPut]
        public IActionResult UpdateEmployee([FromBody] Employee employee)
        {
            if (employee == null)
                return BadRequest();

            if (employee.FirstName == string.Empty || employee.LastName == string.Empty)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Name/FirstName", "The name or first name shouldn't be empty");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var employeeToUpdate = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(employee.EmployeeId);

            if (employeeToUpdate == null)
                return NotFound();

            _employeeRepository.UpdateEmployee(employee);

            return NoContent(); //success
        }
```

Comment: It would be more relevant to see the api controllers and actions. The use of `Put` is uncommon, didn't you mean Post?

Comment: I have copied the code snippet from api controller  HttpPut action to update the record. please help

Comment: When you do `UpdateEmployee(employeeToUpdate)` you willl lose the changes but do you still get the error? And is it areal error or a problem with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost to the point you can use Dependency Injection to get the values.
In the .razor class if you want to use the repository to get an employee by ID, do something like this.

```
[Inject]
public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository {get;set;}

public void MyMethod()
```

{
var employeeToUpdate = EmployeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(employee.EmployeeId);

}